# How to send a zip file containing bunch of pdf's directly to a printer?

Tags: command-line, printing, pdf, unzip

I receive regularly a bunch of pdf's as a single zip file. I would like to send these directly to a printer.

I found a nice script which allows using the right-click context menu to send the pdf's directly to a printer.

[Print pdf file directly without opening it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170290/print-pdf-file-directly-without-opening-it/170301)

Now I would like to modify the script so that it would unzip the file and then send the pdf's to printer. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now got it working. 
One must use "NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS" as there are multiple files.

```
#!/bin/bash 

current_nautilus_path=$(echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS" | sed -e 's/%/\\x/g' -e 's_^file://__' | xargs -0 printf "%b") #get the URI variable from nautilus
mkdir -p /tmp/unzip_files "$current_nautilus_path" -d /tmp/unzip_files #unzip selected files to tmp directory 
lpr -r /tmp/unzip_files/*.pdf #print and remove file
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a simple "one liner", you can use the `-p` option of `unzip`

> -p     extract files to pipe (stdout).
>             Nothing but the file data  is  sent  to  stdout,  and  the  files  are  always
>             extracted in binary format, just as they are stored (no conversions).

So it's a matter of piping the output to `lpr`:

```
unzip -p archive_with_lots_of_pdfs.zip | lpr
```

and you can easily adapt the script you linked to use this command.

**Note** that the `-c` option is *similar*

> -c     extract files to stdout/screen (``CRT'').

But it prints the filename **before** the actual content. This will break your `lpr` command and *probably* will print garbage.

Comment: Great! I tried, with the following command, but it printed only the first pdf contained in the zipfile.

$ unzip -p invoices_11379\ \(20\).zip | lpr

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mkdir -p files
unzip pdfs.zip -d files
lpr files/*.pdf
```

1. Command will create directory
2. Unzip zip to `files` directory
3. Print all pdf files

Edit, nautilus script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /tmp/unzip_files
unzip "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI" -d /tmp/unzip_files   #unzip selected files to tmp directory
lpr -r /tmp/unzip_files/*.pdf   #print and remove file
```

Comment: How to make this into a script that I can save in nautilus scripts, so that I could envoke it throught the right-click menu in nautilus?

Comment: @OssiViljakainen I don't have nautilus installed but after googling some things about it, I edited answer with code for it. It should work, so try it.

Comment: I tried your above solution: the individual lines do work. But the script doesn't. The issue with the script is that I think the variable "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI" doesn't give the URI correctly, and as a result the script doesn't do anything.

Comment: should echo command be used, along these lines: http://www.frenssen.be/2010-05-09-printing-a-file-from-the-right-click-context-menu-in-nautilus/